# Tomcat 7 Failed to create work directory

Tags: java, servlets, tomcat7

I am trying to deploy a WAR generated with Eclipse in my Tomcat 7 webapps directory.
There are several Exceptions like this:

> Warnung: Failed to create work directory [C:\Program Files\Apache
>   Software Foundation\Apache Tomcat
>   7.0.22\work\Catalina\localhost\QAServlet] for context [/QAServlet]

When I start the tomcat in Eclipse, it works fine.

Can someone help?

Comment: Permissions problem?  http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/security-manager-howto.html

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It's because `Program files` is protected system folder. The easiest solution is install tomcat in some unsecured folder (E.g. `C:\tomcat`).

Answer (score 0):

May be your war doesn't contain the MANIFEST file. From Eclipse, be sure to check the option that the manifest is present in the war.